# Why does getting soap in your eyes cause redness and irritation?

Tags: human-eye

I am wondering why do eyes become red after getting soap in them. What is the cause behind it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because of the soaps chemical nature. They are alkaline agents and human eyes have a very low tolerance for alkalinity. Human eyes are roughly neutral with a pH of around 7, and soaps are around 7.5 to 9.

The eye can't handle the alkaline object as it is potentially harmful to the eye so it will start watering to get rid of the alien substance. Blood vessels then enlarge, coming closer to the surface of the eye, making them appear red.

Most soaps are tested before released to make sure if they come into contact with eyes they are non-toxic. Baby soaps have a lower pH as well to make sure that the baby doesn't come to harm.

Either way, its probably best not to put it in your eyes.

See [here](http://www.sciencefocus.com/qa/why-does-shampoo-make-your-eyes-sting) for more information.

Comment: Seriously, the page you link looks (in general) as realiable as yahoo answers.

Comment: @TomášZato looks can be deceiving

Comment: This does not answer the question. Yes, soap/shampoo has different pH values from the standard eye environment, but that is not a really surprising answer. Why do different pH values cause redness? If we could make a "soap" that contains almost the same ingredients as actual soap but has its pH fixed to 7 still cause red eyes? Will any other substance that is wildly different from water but has ph=7 also cause red eyes? What is the *function* of the redness (if it has any except to tell us that we rather not put *that* stuff into our eyes). Etc.

Comment: @AnoE I don't think its a function, more a reaction

Comment: Yeah... take my longer comment up there as an incentive to enlarge the answer to the (rather interesting) question. But if it is just a nonfunctional, arbitrary reaction, it would be at least nice to see details about the actual way it comes to pass (i.e., why does the eye get red, why does it not just start watering profusely to dilute the substance down to usual pH values).

Comment: @AnoE if I understand right, the red is simply blood vessels having grown larger and come closer to the surface, which is why we can see the red colour.

Comment: Anecdotally, "tear free" shampoo still hurts *my* eyes.

Comment: Basically, the eye would react to anything that is not similar (w.r.t osmolarity and pH) to the solution that covers it. Eye will react to neutral substances too. Tap water (without chlorine or other such chemicals) would also hurt in the beginning.

Comment: So how do red eyes help to get rid of that pH change?

Answer (score 1):

When soap gets into the eye, Our immune system reacts to the foreign substance, it releases a chemical known as **histamine** as a part of the inflammatory response.

Now as result of this, blood vessels in the eyes become enlarged, dilated or swollen.

It leads to redness in eyes.

---

[Source](http://www.allaboutvision.com/conditions/red-eyes.htm)

Comment: XXX has chemicals is not a way to start an answer on scientific page.

Comment: Why so much downvotes, Any reason.

Comment: What is the mistake in the answer. Is it scientifically incorrect ?

Comment: This is a scientific page. You're free to chose whatever formulation you like for an answer, but you should also include references.

Comment: @Tensor_Product, the downvotes are likely because you do not answer the question. You are more or less reformulating the question with a few more words.

Comment: Do you have a source that histamine is released in response to irritants, rather than allergens?